# Auto-Authentication in Spring Security

Tags: spring, security, authorization

I have a Secured Spring MVC project. I would like to auto-authorize users when a new account is successfully created. This is usually done where a new account is created, as follows:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/spitter")
public class SpitterController {

...
@Inject AuthenticationManager authMgr;
@Inject AccountService accountService;
...

  @RequestMapping(value="/register", method=POST)
  public String processRegistration(
        @ModelAttribute("spitter") @Valid Spitter form,
        BindingResult result) {

        convertPasswordError(result);

        String psswd = form.getPassword();
        accountService.registerAccount(toAccount(form), psswd, result);

        // Auto-Authentication
        Authentication authRequest = 
          new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(form.getUsername(), psswd);
        Authentication authResult = authMgr.authenticate(authRequest);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                             .setAuthentication(authResult);

      return (result.hasErrors() ? VN_REG_FORM : VN_REG_OK);
    }
 ...
}
```

I'm using Java configuration. My security configuration file is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }     

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
      .and()
        .logout()
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
      .and()
      .rememberMe()
        .tokenRepository(new InMemoryTokenRepositoryImpl())
        .tokenValiditySeconds(2419200)
        .key("spittrKey")
      .and()
       .httpBasic()
         .realmName("Spittr")
      .and()
      .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user").hasAnyAuthority("admin", "user")
        .antMatchers("/admin").hasAuthority("admin")
        .antMatchers("spitter/me").authenticated()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/spittles").authenticated()
        .anyRequest().permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.userDetailsService(new UserDetailsServiceAdapter(accountService))
          .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

}
```

If I were using XML configuration, I would have an authentication manager element:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  ...
</authentication-manager/>
```

where the alias is set because one gets an authentication manager from the http element in addition to the authentication-manager element and you have to distinguish between the two.

However, with my configuration, there is apparently no       AuthenticationManager being created:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field:   org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager   spittr.web.SpitterController.authMngr; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

...

This is a bit surprising. I thought that at least one such bean would be created by default. I'm not sure what the best solution is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its not exposed as a spring bean by default, you need to override the `authenticationManagerBean()` methon on `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```
@Bean(name="myAuthenticationManager")
@Override
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
}
```

Ref: http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-javaconfig-build/1.0.0.M1/api-reference/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html#authenticationManagerBean()